# Butterknife unable to bind in Robolectric test

Tags: robolectric, butterknife

When I run the app Butterknife binds ok, but in my Robolectric 3.0 test I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceGeneralFragment
at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:279)
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceGeneralFragment.onCreateView(TaskInstanceGeneralFragment.java:75)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.$$robo$$performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.$$robo$$moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.$$robo$$moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.$$robo$$run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.$$robo$$execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.$$robo$$run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java)
at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:130)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:95)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:230)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:85)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:437)
at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java)
at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$post(Handler.java:326)
at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.$$robo$$enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1523)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.$$robo$$commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.$$robo$$commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java)
at org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(SupportFragmentTestUtil.java:22)
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TestTaskInstanceGeneralFragment.setup(TestTaskInstanceGeneralFragment.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:638)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:57)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.elt.passsystem.widget.residential.ResidentialTaskContextView cannot be cast to com.elt.passsystem.widget.residential.ResidentialTaskContextView
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceBaseFragment$$ViewBinder.bind(TaskInstanceBaseFragment$$ViewBinder.java:12)
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceGenMedBaseFragment$$ViewBinder.bind(TaskInstanceGenMedBaseFragment$$ViewBinder.java:9)
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceGenMedBaseFragment$$ViewBinder.bind(TaskInstanceGenMedBaseFragment$$ViewBinder.java:7)
at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
... 85 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceGenMedBaseFragment.addRadioGroupListener(TaskInstanceGenMedBaseFragment.java:74)
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TaskInstanceGeneralFragment.onCreateView(TaskInstanceGeneralFragment.java:80)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:130)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:95)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:230)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:85)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:116)
at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java)
at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1523)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
at org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(SupportFragmentTestUtil.java:22)
at com.elt.passsystem.fragment.residential.task.TestTaskInstanceGeneralFragment.setup(TestTaskInstanceGeneralFragment.java:75)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:65)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:638)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:57)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**The Test setup**

```
    @Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    Injector.getInstance().setComponent(
            DaggerTestComponent.builder()
                    .mockGlobalConfigsModule(new MockGlobalConfigsModule(true))
                    .mockDataAccessModule(new MockDataAccessModule(true))
                    .jobManagerModule(new JobManagerModule(RuntimeEnvironment.application))
                    .build()
    );
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LogCustom.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(LogCustom.class, "v", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());


    fragment = new TaskInstanceGeneralFragment();
    SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment, EpisodeOfCareDetailActivity.class);

    completeRadioGroup = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.radio_group_complete);
    reasonLinearLayout = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_reason);
}
```

**The Fragment onCreateView**

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);  
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_residential_activity_general, null, false); 
try {         
      ButterKnife.bind(this, root);     
} catch (Exception e) {         
      e.printStackTrace();     
}
```

Please can someone help to fathom this out as I'd like to  use butterknife and robolectric together.

Comment: My guess is because of `PowerMock` , why do you need it? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks for your help

Comment: If you like to use PowerMock you can try official workaround documentation https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Using-PowerMock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PowerMock` is quite often conflicting with `Robolectric`. The issue is resolved as author removed it from tests